# How to improve ASP.NET web application performance?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance

To be more specific... When someone clicks a link on my web application, can that user be redirected immediately after the click and then wait for the page (user controls) to load. (Can the user controls load one by one with a priority or something?)

Right know, there is a delay after the user clicks on a link and then gets redirected.

Comment: If there actually is a delay between the link and redirect (I assume "taken to where the link points to"), there is something wrong. Sure, the page won't come immediately, but the redirect should happen immediately. So do you mean "the page loads slowly" or "someone clicks a link, nothing happens for a moment, and only after that the browser starts loading"?

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do:

- Check how you're using the ViewState if you're not careful it gets
  quite big. But some parts of your app might be depending on it so
  it's kind of situational.
- Caching of pages or just controls
- AJAX - while it doesn't feel as natural as in the MVC, it's still an option
  for Web Forms
- Script & Css bundling and minification - less requests
  for more data are always faster then more requests for less data

These are things I'd start with. From my experience excesive ViewState is the place where you can gain the most but a usually it takes quite some effort to get rid of it since just turning it off might make some of your controls not working properly on postback.

This is just a start but going deeper would require much deeper knowladge of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX technology to create the required responsiveness of your application.

In fact, you only need one page. You could load all actions performed (and the updated HTML/JS) using AJAX.

I would advise to read into that subject. You could use jQuery or similar frameworks to do the communication with the web server.

Required reading: [ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax).

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try to redo your application with `AJAX` approach:
here is a smart article about it http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/use-ajax-to-deliver-dynamic-updates

Take a look to `AJAX` technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are using classic Asp.NET and therefore, webforms.

One way to speed things would be to switch to the Razor platform, which eases things a bit (by preventing unnecessary postbacks).

Alternatively, if you don't want to remake the whole application, you could use a simple html link instead of an `asp:hyperlink`.

Comment: You are simply throwing the entire ASP.NET Web Forms away to use ASP.NET MVC and Razor? What to do with all those user controls already used?

Comment: That is why I also offered an alternative that doesn't require throwing all that have already been done. If it's not a mature application (not much user controls and pages already written) changing the platform would be my number 1 solution.

Comment: But just changing one server control to a HTML element doesn't help anything. The performance in rendering a `asp:Hyperlink` vs a `a href=` is none.

Comment: Clicking on an `asp:hyperlink` will trigger a postback event, thus creating a delay between the click action and the actual redirection.

Comment: `<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" Text="link here" />` renders to `<a href="http://www.google.com">link here</a>`. No postback.